# Django 1.6 EmailMessage module errors when serializing Excel Attachment

Tags: django, excel

I created excel object with `xlwt` module. But when I try to email it as an attachment `EmailMessage()` tries to serialize it and errors with '`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'`. How can I email this attachment in Django?

```
  File "/home/git/bot_server/bot_server/bot_data/views.py", line 590, in email_export
    email.send()
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 274, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/console.py", line 34, in send_messages
    self.write_message(message)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/console.py", line 17, in write_message
    msg = message.message()
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 241, in message
    msg = self._create_message(msg)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 299, in _create_message
    return self._create_attachments(msg)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 312, in _create_attachments
    msg.attach(self._create_attachment(*attachment))
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 339, in _create_attachment
    attachment = self._create_mime_attachment(content, mimetype)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 327, in _create_mime_attachment
    Encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/encoders.py", line 45, in encode_base64
    encdata = _bencode(orig)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/encoders.py", line 31, in _bencode
    hasnewline = (s[-1] == '\n')
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 192, in __getitem__
    return self._headers[header.lower()][1]
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Email function:

```
def email_export(export, user_email):
    subject = 'Stuff'
    from_address = 'noreply@foo'
    body = "Hello"
    recip = [user_email]
    email = EmailMessage(subject, body, from_address, recip)
    email.attach('community_support_excel.xls', export, 'application/ms-excel')
    email.send()
```

Some of the excel function:

```
def export_xls(queryset):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=mymodel.xls'
    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    ws = wb.add_sheet("MyModel")

    more stuff.....
    wb.save(response)
    return response
```

Comment: please show how you create worksheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that I was trying to email a HTTPResponse object as a attachment in which was not allowed. What I had to do was store the excel sheet in a object created with io.BytesIO(). Then send the attachment with export_object.getvalues().

Comment: Hi - can you please provide your solution as it is the excepted answer.